# When should i save settings with QSettings in a class?

Tags: qt4, qsettings

I used to save settings in `closeEvent` , now i found that's bit of flaw , because when you close a window , that function will be called as well. ( my app have a system tray , and hide to system tray ability )

So when should i save the settings with QSettings ? I shouldn't be calling this in destruction function , right ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's definitely fine to use QSettings in destructors. I've done that for years and not had any problems.